# Installing packages on CentOS 6.5

Tags: g++, centos6, yum

Sorry for posting a generic question. I am trying to install 'rest-client' for a ruby on rails project as `gem install rest-client`, which fails saying

```
make: g++: Command not found 
make: *** [unf.o] Error 127
make failed, exit code 2
```

So I checked to see if g++ is installed or not. Apparently gcc is installed(gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313) but not g++. I have tried to install it with yum, but no success. Below are the commands I used.

```
yum install gcc-c++
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Later I added  http://people.centos.org/tru/devtools-2/devtools-2.repo repo and tried to run `yum install devtoolset-2-gcc` which failed saying `Requires: policycoreutils-python`
So I tried to install it using yum but no luck!. Then I tried to install g++ and its dependencies manually(downloading the rpm's) but I felt like I am going down a rabbit hole.

Please help!! I am not sure where to start.

Here is the output

```
adobe-linux-x86_64                                   Adobe Systems Incorporated                                                                             2
base                                                 CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                      352
centosplus                                           CentOS-6 - Plus                                                                                       68
contrib                                              CentOS-6 - Contrib                                                                                     0
couchbase                                            Couchbase package repository                                                                           7
epel                                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                    12,214
extras                                               CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                     62
fasttrack                                            CentOS - fasttrack                                                                                    66
ius                                                  IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                               362
ius-debuginfo                                        IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Debug                                        71
ius-dev                                              IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Dev                                          11
ius-dev-debuginfo                                    IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Dev Debug Info                                5
ius-dev-source                                       IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Dev Source                                    0
ius-source                                           IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Source                                        0
mysql-connectors-community                           MySQL Connectors Community                                                                            21
mysql-tools-community                                MySQL Tools Community                                                                                 33
mysql56-community                                    MySQL 5.6 Community Server                                                                           229
remi                                                 Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                   3,230
remi-safe                                            Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                           590
rpmforge                                             Red Hat Enterprise 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                          4,718
slc6-scl                                             Scientific Linux CERN (SLC6) - SCL addons                                                          2,472
testing-devtools-2-centos-6                          testing 2 devtools for CentOS 6                                                                      119
updates                                              CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                 1,555
webtatic                                             Webtatic Repository EL6 - x86_64
```

Another weird thing is when I do `yum search all policycoreutils` it returns a result but when try to install it says no package found

Comment: What does `yum repolist` output? I don't think that's the official devtools repo. I think you probably want [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/3/html/User_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Install.html) or [this](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/). I'd probably suggest removing that devtools-2 repo.

Comment: use this command `yum install gcc-c++` source http://superuser.com/questions/590808/yum-install-gcc-g-doesnt-work-anymore-in-centos-6-4

Answer (score 0):

If you want install ruby (and ready for ruby on rails and others (centos 6.x on a clean VM minimal install, I used 32bits in this case) follow the next steps:

```
curl -O https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
tar -xjvf ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
cd ruby-2.3.1
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ zlib-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel openssl-devel libffi-devel sqlite-devel
sudo yum install -y http://mirror.compevo.com/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y v8
./configure --disable-install-doc --disable-install-rdoc --disable-install-capi
make
sudo make install
gem update --system --no-ri --no-rdoc
sudo /usr/local/bin/gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

In this case gcc-c++ is not necessary but other gems needs that like rest-client